# Django Forms not showing

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to use Django provided forms instead of manually creating them with HTML. When I do this, however, they do not appear. The questions/answers I have found on this site have so far been unable to solve my issue. (unless I am reading them wrong.)

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class KeywordForm(forms.Form):
    input_keywords = forms.CharField(label="Keywords", max_length='100')


class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    input_location = forms.CharField(label="Location", max_length="250")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import KeywordForm, LocationForm

def search_view(request):
    keyword_form = KeywordForm()
    location_form = LocationForm()

    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'keyword_form': keyword_form, 'location_form': location_form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('search/', views.search_view, name='search'),
]
```

base.html

```
    {% block search %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="row align-items-center">
                <form action="search" method="GET">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{ keyword_form }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{ location_form }}
                    </div>
<!--                        <label for="inputKeywords" class="form-label">Keywords</label>-->
<!--                        <input class="form-control" id="inputKeywords" type="text" name="inputKeywords" placeholder="Enter Keywords...">-->
<!--                    </div>-->
<!--                    <div class="col-sm-2">-->
<!--                        <label for="inputLocation" class="form-label">Location</label>-->
<!--                        <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation" placeholder="Enter location...">-->
<!--                    </div>-->
                    <div class="col">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Per request: search_results.html, which isn't finished due to the forms not showing up in `base.html`.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block search %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <form action="search" method="GET">
                {{ keyword_form }}
                {{ location_form }}
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: do you have any errors shown in the browser console ?

Comment: No, the only error I get is the favicon.

Comment: @LuckBox Please show `search_results.html`, you have shown `base.html` instead. Also you render the forms in `base.html`?? I assume you extend this template in other templates so ideally your forms should be rendered in `search_results.html` (the view renders this template).

Comment: I am rendering this specific layout to `base.html`, while `search_results.html` has a different layout for the forms.

Comment: @LuckBox You say "_forms not showing up in base.html_" that is normal of course, why would they show up there if their view does not pass the forms in the context?

Comment: Is `{'keyword_form': keyword_form, 'location_form': location_form}` not proper context?

Comment: @LuckBox `search_view` passes that context to `search_results.html`. If you expect these forms to be rendered in other pages rendered by some other view without passing them in the context there, then the current behavior of your code is totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

In `base.html` replace this:

```
  {% block search %}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form class="row align-items-center">
            <form action="search" method="GET">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    {{ keyword_form }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    {{ location_form }}
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
                </div>
            </form>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

with this:

```
  {% block search %}
    
  {% endblock search %}
```

Let me see if i can explain clearly what's happening here..

You created a view for `search_results.html` so when you render that page the view passes the context variable to it, which includes the forms. All good 'till here.
From the code you shared i see that then you went ahead and added the Django Template Language to render those forms directly in `base.html`. But that won't work because `base.html` doesn't have access to the context variable you're passing to `search_results.html`.

When you extend a template and you add content within blocks that are present in the parent template, what happens is that the block in question is **overwritten**.

So in your case, whatever you're writing between `search blocks` in base.html will be wholly overwritten by what's in between those same blocks in `search_results.html`.

From what i see there are no errors in the code so I think all you have to do is to work on your `search_results.html` template. And when you test if it works or not do so on `search_results.html`, not anywhere else, because that's the template that will have access to the context dictionary.

The problem might also be that for some reason those form elements are empty, or that something is wrong at some other step of the way. The template doesn't mind being passed empty context variables so you should also consider that maybe the forms **are** being passed to the template but they're just empty. You have to run little tests for these things. Try passing a variable containing a simple string to the template and try to render that. Does it work? Good, at least you know that the problem is somewhere else. Doesn't it? Even better, you're one step closer to the solution.